# Take n biggest and lowest values with tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to get the k most possitive and negatives values given a dataframe, without having to store them both separately. Currently I'm doing something like the following for k = 2:

```
df %>%
arrange(desc(n)) %>%
top_n(2)

df %>%
arrange(desc(n)) %>%
top_n(-2))
```

But I want to know if there is a simpler way to perform this without having to store them and then `bind_rows` . I suppose so, because this is really handy to do some `geom_bars`.

Suppose that I'm using any tibble, for instance something like:

```
df <- tibble(x = 1:10, n = 1:10)
```

And I want to get the values `1,2,9,10`

Comment: Based on your example, you mean the largest and smallest numbers in the data frame, not positive and negative. I think it would be worth editing question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `slice` after `arrange`ing by 'n'.  Here, we call the `arrange` only once

```
library(dplyr)
top_n_rows <- 2
df %>% 
    arrange(n) %>%
    slice(sort(c(seq_len(top_n_rows),  n() - seq_len(top_n_rows) + 1)))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#      x     n
#  <int> <int>
#1     1     1
#2     2     2
#3     9     9
#4    10    10
```

---

Or another option is `row_number()`

```
df %>%
   arrange(n) %>%
   slice(c(head(row_number(), top_n_rows), tail(row_number(), top_n_rows)))
```

---

If we are just subsetting the first n and last n rows without considering any columns to order

```
rbind(head(df, top_n_rows), tail(df, top_n_rows))
```

Or with `row.names`

```
df[c(head(row.names(df), top_n_rows), tail(row.names(df), top_n_rows)),]
```

Comment: I like the second one! More legible imo

Comment: Should we consider the general case where the length of the data frame is less than 2*top_n_rows? What should the result be?

Comment: @MarkNeal it depends on what the OP may need.  If it is the full data.frame or an error

Answer (score 2):

For positive/negatives values, I came across this solution

```
df %>%
  group_by(n < 0) %>%
  top_n(2, abs(n)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  slice(which(rank(n) %in% 1:2), which(rank(desc(n)) %in% 1:2))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
      x     n
  <int> <int>
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     9     9
4    10    10
```

Answer (score 0):

We can precalculate the rows which we want to select

```
no_rows <- 2
num <- c(1:no_rows, (nrow(df) - no_rows + 1):nrow(df))
```

and then we can use `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% slice(num)

#      x     n
#  <int> <int>
#1     1     1
#2     2     2
#3     9     9
#4    10    10
```

Or `filter`

```
df %>% filter(row_number() %in% num)
```

Obviously this also works with direct subsetting :

```
df[num, ]
```

---

Apart from that when using `top_n` we don't need to `arrange` the data, we can directly use it

```
bind_rows(df %>% top_n(no_rows, n), df %>% top_n(-no_rows, n)) %>% arrange_all()
```